# Is it possible to refer/use to ANOTHER mapper/datasource from a myBatis mapper?

Tags: java, datasource, mybatis

I am trying to figure out (and so far it seems I am out of luck), if it possible to refer (for `association`, for example) to a nested select from a different mapper/datasource ? Or may be some HashMap, which I could prepare manually beforehand..

What am I trying to achieve is basically the following:

1. say we have a database ONE, which has a table with a list of items. Every item has a field like "external_id"
2. we have also a database TWO, which is on different host and/or of a different driver type, which has a table with `id; name` pairs
3. And I would like to return a Mapped type which would contain fields from BOTH databases ONE and TWO.

Any ideas? So far I can only suggest constructing 2 POJOs independently, one with a returned ResultSet from db ONE and another with a list of id/name-pairs from db TWO and building the resulting object "by hands". But this is so boring...